# How to pass props in Vue Router when using Typescript and class component decorator

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-class-components

I am trying to get access to my props when using a class component decorator, but I keep getting back 'undefined'. The documentation on Vue Router doesn't document any support for using TS. Below is my current setup and link to a Codesanbox.

Codesabox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-ts-router-forked-tsgsu

Router.ts:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import CarsView from "./components/Cars.vue";
import OnboardCarset from "./components/Carsform.vue";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    { path: "/", redirect: "/cars", component: CarsView },
    { path: "/cars", component: CarsView },
    {
      path: "/cars/:id",
      name: "car-edit",
      props: true,
      component: OnboardCarset
    }
  ]
});
```

Main.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import vuetify from "./vuetify";
import router from "./router";
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app> <router-view></router-view></v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
};
</script>
```

Cars.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'car-edit', params: { id: tab } }">
      Cars
    </router-link>
    <router-view name="car-edit" :propsMessage="myArray" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Cars extends Vue {
  public tab: number = 2;
  public myArray: Array<string> = [];
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.myArray = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
  }
}
</script>
```

Carsform.vue

```
<template>
  <div>Cars Form</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Carsform extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: Array })
  propsMessage!: string[];
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(this.propsMessage);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prop name should be the same as  `params` field :

```
<template>
  <div>Cars Form</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Carsform extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: Number })
  id!: number;
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(this.id);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: it's my pleasure that i could help you

Comment: Only thing though is on Refresh or when I hit the route "(https://tsgsu.csb.app/cars/2)" , its retuning 'undefined'' , Any thoughts?

Comment: try to put that log inside mounted hook

Comment: ok i got it you're not navigating to the same page by the same way, there's difference between clicking on a link and refreshing the page

Comment: when you click on the link you provide the params but when you refresh you don't

Comment: How do I get that to function properly?

Comment: pass that array in route definition, replace `props:true` by `props:  {propsMessage: ["One", "Two", "Three"] }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224697/discussion-between-user992731-and-boussadjra-brahim).

Comment: That works however, given architecture I am working in I dont have the option to define the array in the router. It needs to live in the 'car.vue' file

Comment: provide that array as default value of the prop